# Android: Can't style ActionBar menu text

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to create a custom styling for the ActionBar. Specifically i'm trying to change the menu item color.

I applied these stylings:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBarMenuText</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBarMenuText</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarMenuText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>
```

The background is applying but the menu text colour is not. What am i missing?

I know this was asked many times, but none of the solutions helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it, Since `android:actionMenuTextColor` is defined in `Theme.Sherlock.Light` I needed to add it to my main custom theme which inherits from it and not to the style that inherits from `Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar`:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>
```